# random number statement is not working with my toInt text field input

Tags: ios, swift

error bellow: Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue Int?, @lvalue UInt32)

```
@IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!

@IBAction func submit(sender: AnyObject) {
    var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(4)+1//look at the first if declaration. This is were my question is
    var guess = textBox.text.toInt()
    if guess == randomNumber {             //error: Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue Int?, @lvalue UInt32)
        guess.text = "Well done, correct!"
    }
    else if guess < 0 {
        guess.text = "WHAT!?!? that wasn't even an option"
    }
    else if guess > 5 {
        guess.text = "WHAT!?!? that wasn't even an option"
    }
    else {
        guess.text = "WRONG the correct answer was \(randomNumber)"
    }
```

Please tell me why I'm getting an error using an == with the arcforrandom and how i can fix this and have it run like i want it to. All answers are much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

convert `Uint` to `Int`

```
var randomNumber = Int( arc4random_uniform(4)+1 )
```

and..

why `guess.text` you mean `result.text`?

Answer (score 0):

`UInt` means unsigned int only possitive numbers are allowed here.

`Int` allows both positive and negative

But both have same range (2^31)

So typecast your `UInt` to `Int`

```
 if guess == Int(randonNumber) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your randomNumber is of the type UInt32. You have to convert it to an Int.
You can read about it in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID324)

```
var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(4)+1)
```